# Sql Injection login bypass

Tags: php, authentication, sql-injection

I am trying to practice sql injection by bypassing my own login page but I don't know how to make it vulnerable to sqli ,can you tell me what to do ? 
this is the php code :

```
<?php
    @ob_start();
    session_start();require('db.php');
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if(!empty ($rows)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
```

Comment: thanks in advance..

Comment: Well, you're lucky. It's already vulnerable to sql-i.

Comment: Terrible use of `!empty` there… [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @Danielius but when I write on the password  or 1=1 it doesn't log on

Comment: @Dark_Angel try `' TRUNCATE users` if all users are gone - sql-i was successful. Sorry, I am not hacker. I better try to make my script safe!

Comment: @Dark_Angel once one of my friends asked to do such thing about sql-i. http://danieliaus.puslapiai.lt/sql_i/index.php?id=1 maybe it would help you...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can give you a clue.

This is your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
```

By typing 1 = 1 will not bypass it. Just take a piece of paper and a pencil and imagine how your query will look like. In your case will output:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '1 = 1' AND password = '1 = 1'
```

The query is correct, although there's no username called '1 = 1' with a password '1 = 1'.

Now the vulnerability:

You need to pass on user and password parameters, a string that can trick the query.

For example:

```
x' OR '1' = '1
```

What will produce this input?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'x' OR '1' = '1' AND password = 'x' OR '1' = '1'
```

How can you prevent this injection? Taken from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

> Primary Defenses:
>
> Option #1: Use of Prepared Statements (Parameterized Queries)
>
> Option #2: Use of Stored Procedures
>
> Option #3: Escaping all User Supplied Input
>
> Additional Defenses:
>
> Also Enforce: Least Privilege
>
> Also Perform: White List Input Validation